# Django not updating static location setting

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-static

I have a project that has been running just fine for about 6 months. Static files have been working perfectly, and everything is great. I have my `static` files located in a folder as so:

`/var/www/html/static/`

In my `settings.py` file, I have the static section setup like so:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
     '/var/www/html/static/',
     )
```

This has been working just fine.

However, I now want to move the `static` folder to a different location. Specifically, I want to move it inside the main project directory. My project is located at `/var/www/html/shq/` so I want to have my `static` directory located at `/var/www/html/shq/static/`. I moved the folder, then updated my `settings.py` file to look like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
     '/var/www/html/shq/static/',
     )
```

However, it didn't work. The Django project is still referencing the old location.

What am I missing here? Why isn't the Django project using the new location of `/var/www/html/shq/static/`?

**EDIT**

This is what the tail end of my `settings.py` file looks like:

```
119 STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
120   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
121   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
122 ]
123
124 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
125 STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/html/collected_static/'
126 MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
127 MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/html/shq/media/'
128 STATICFILES_DIRS = [
129     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
130     '/var/www/html/shq/static/',
131     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try doing something like this. I think it returns the list of directories that django looks for to find static files. Might help debugging.

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders
from pprint import pprint
pprint(finders.find("", all=True))
```

Also, I may not be fully understanding your scenario, but you might confirm that the STATIC_ROOT is set to the location where you want to serve your static files (where your webserver will serve the files).  The STATIC_DIRS setting tells collectstatic where to find static files, but the STATIC_ROOT is where collectstatic will actually place the files.

Comment: `STATIC_ROOT` is set to a separate directory so that static files are stored there for production (and when `DEBUG=False`). I entered that script you posted into a `python` editor, but it complains that the `STATICFILES_FINDERS` isn't set, even though it is (I have the two finders listed). Not sure why this is always so frustratingly challenging. -- Edit -- I also updated the post to show more of my `settings.py` file

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Not surprisingly, it was an easy fix once I figured it out.

It had *nothing* to do with my Django settings and everything to do with Apache.

**Original**

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/static/
```

So no matter what I did in my Django `settings.py` file, Apache was overriding that to send `/static/` requested to the wrong directory.

**New Apache Setting**

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/shq/static/
```

Now the proper static files are being referenced. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future :)